# How to implement the auto-suggest UI using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, tagging

I am writing the photos app. The user can click on a person's photo and tag it. I want to implement the tagging as follows:

- 1) The user looks at the photo and recognizes John Smith.
- 2) The user clicks on the text input field.
- 3) The user starts typing 'Jo...'
- 4) **A list of suggested gmail accounts appears** for the user to choose from (e.g. johny123@gmail.com, johnsmith@gmail.com, joanna@gmail.com).
- 5) The user clicks on the correct account (johnsmith@gmail.com) in the list.
- 6) The photo is tagged with the account the user has chosen.

I have implemented many parts except for the 4th. Below I present the code for the current UI:

```
// This method is invoked after the user finishes typing and clicks enter.
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    // other code
    ...

    String usersEntry = textView.getText().toString();
    tagPhotoWith(usersLabel);
    return true;
}
```

Currently whatever text the user types becomes the photo tag after the user clicks enter. Instead, I want the app to show the list of suggested gmail.com accounts so that the user could select the appropriate account for tagging. **How to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a AutoCompleteTextView to get suggestions for saved strings(as in your case, they are Email-IDs, whether fetched from database or pre-defined in the program at some time).

Here, an adapter is set over the AutoCompleteTextView to get string array/Arraylist set for the input box as soon as user types 2 or 3 characters of the string.

```
AutoCompleteTextView textProductView;
textProductView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);

ArrayAdapter<String> etAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, ITEMS);
textProductView.setAdapter(etAdapter);
```

Here, ITEMS is a string array defined as per data fetched from user/database or predefined in activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Display the auto complete with good GUI, You can go for  either popupwindow or you can use customize listview or recyclerview and use setvisibility Gone/Visible in your activty and xml.

I have prepared customized autosearch using Listview view for my app like below.

```
//activity_main.xml
<LinearLayout 
 //  parent layout
     android:orientation="vertical"
>
     < ....      /* your code for toolbar */          ..../>
     <Edittext 
       android:id="@+id/edittext"
       /*  your customization*/
      />
      <Relativelayou
      android:height="match_parent"
      android:width=""match_parent"
      >
          <LinearLayout > /*your main xml code*/ </LinearLayout>
          <ListView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/lstvw"
           android:dividerHeight="0dp"
           android:visibility="gone">

         </ListView>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

In your MainActivity use EditText.addTextChangedListener.

```
//MainActivity.java
   EditText ed;
   ListView lst;
   ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> array1=new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxt);
    lst= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstvw);
    lst.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int  ount, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str=ed.getText().toString();
            array1.clear();
            lst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
            {
                if(array.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    array1.add(array.get(i));
                }
            }
            if((ArrayAdapter<String> )lst.getAdapter()!=null){
            ((ArrayAdapter<String> )lst.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();}
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            lst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array1);
    ad.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    lst.setAdapter(ad);

}}
```

Here you can use custom listview row as per your design.

Hope this will helps you!!!